# template<typename> - how does it work?

Tags: c++, templates, arguments

I have come across such syntax:

```
template<typename>
struct is_const{static const bool value = 0;};
```

How will this code behave and how could it be applied? I didn't find any example or explanation in the Internet.

I am wondering about lack of the argument name (e.g. T).

Comment: If you're wondering about the lack of an actual *name* for the "typename", the name is optional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a primary template which takes a single template argument and has a static `bool` member equal to `0`. It is likely that this is the primary template definition for a type trait and that there is a corresponding specialization elsewhere which looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_const<const T>
{static const bool value = 1;};
```

This would allow you to check if a type is `const` qualified like so:

```
static_assert(!is_const<int>::value, "wat");
static_assert(is_const<const int>::value, "wat");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
class SampleClass
{
public:
    T values [2];
    SampleClass(T first, T second)
    {
       values[0]=first; 
       values[1]=second;
    }
};
```

Try Something like this typename are generic way of programming. search for  generic programming c++. You will get alot of resources

Answer (score 0):

On a basic level of explanation, each time the template is used the compiler generates a version of the templated struct, class, function, etc.

for example:

```
template<typename T>
struct StructName
{
    T memberVariable;
};
```

when this code is used:

```
StructName<float> variable = StructName<float>();
```

the compiler generates:

```
struct StructName
{
    float memberVariable;
};
```

you can read more about this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming